# i can't draw anything using getGraphics() method

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw in JPANEL using getgraphics but it still doesn't work, I don't understand why, I don't know where the error is.

maybe it happens because i'm using threads,also this part of code is based on a game made with java swing (Dragon tale).

my code

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;
    private Thread thread;
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;

    public GamePanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();

        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }


    private void init() {
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
        draw(g);
        drawToScreen();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 1);
    }

    private void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = this.getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * 2, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hook yourself into `JPanel`s `paintComponent(Graphics)` method

Comment: That is not how custom painting is done.  You don’t ask for a Graphics object.  The system informs you when it wants your window to be drawn, by invoking the painting methods.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.  (Also, do not use threads;   AWT and Swing calls must be invoked in the AWT event dispatch thread and no other thread.)

Comment: You can use threads but the painting has to be done on the AWT/Swing thread or stuff is likely to mess up.  Tutorial on Swing threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: but i don't understand why in my code doesn't work like this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dzhgsVaiSo

Comment: The advice given in that video tutorial is very wrong

Comment: so it's bettter using paintComponent()? than getgraphics()? i'm using that one